# List from Reactions Discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

0

I'm trying to code a simple team randomizer for League of Legends teams (5 for each side), by using a discord bot. So far I was able to send the message, and get reactions, but I don't know how to return the list with the users that reacted to the bot's message to randomize the teams.

So the bot should only return the list when 10 players react to the message. Current code:

```
async def scrim2(ctx, bot):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='*SORTEIO X5 DOS CRIAS*',
        description='Deseja sortear as lanes? \n ✅: Sim \n ❌: Não',
        colour= discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    msg_scrim = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    await msg_scrim.add_reaction('✅')
    await msg_scrim.add_reaction('❌')

    def checkReaction(reaction, user):
        user != bot.user and (str(reaction.emoji) == '✅' or str(reaction.emoji) == '❌')

    def checkReaction1(reaction, user, limit):
        return user != bot.user and (limit == 10) and (str(reaction.emoji) == '')

    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=200, check=checkReaction)
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
        msg_players1 = await ctx.send('Invocadores, reajam abaixo: ')
        await msg_players1.add_reaction('')

        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=200, check=checkReaction1)
        await scrim_sorteio(ctx, bot)

        pass

    elif str(reaction.emoji) == '❌':
        msg_players2 = await ctx.send('Invocadores, reajam abaixo: ')
        await msg_players2.add_reaction('')

        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=200, check=checkReaction1)
        await scrim_sorteio(ctx, bot)

        pass
```

Basically I'd create another function scrim_sorteio to grab that list of players that reacted to the msg and then randomize the teams.

I'm very new to coding, so I'd appreciate the help. Also, no errors are given or anything when I run the code.

UPDATE:

```
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=200, check=checkReaction)
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
        msg_players1 = await ctx.send('Invocadores, reajam abaixo: ')
        await msg_players1.add_reaction('')
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=200, check=checkReaction1)
        players1 = msg_players1.reactions
        print(players1)
        await ctx.send(f'Time 1 {players1}')
```

Now this is just printing a empty list everytime.

Comment: You are somewhat misunderstanding how this flow should work. 

Basically, you have a command which sends a message and then tracks that message for reactions. On **any** new reaction the bot "sees" you can then: 

1) check if it is the message you were tracking
2) check if the required number of reactions has been reached. 

You can do this by checking the `.reactions` field of the message sent along with the Reactions payload.

Comment: Thanks, I made some progress with your comment, but I'm still having problems with printing the correct list of players. It's just printing an empty list regardless of how many users react: I'll edit my post above with the updated code that i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of reactions, you can use `message.reactions`

I think, it can work like this:

```
if len(msg_scrim.reactions) == 10:
  players = msg_scrim.reactions
  random.shuffle(players)
  team1 = players[0:5]
  team2 = players[5:10]
```

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.reactions

Comment: Thanks, I made some progress with your comment, but I'm still having problems with printing the correct list of players. It's just printing an empty list regardless of how many users react: I'll edit my post above with the updated code that i'm using.